# Javascript - Looping Through An Array Of Appointments, Finding Next Available

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, scheduling, date-range

Given `x` amount of days, I am trying to loop through an array of appointments (which are objects that contain a `startDate` and `endDate`) and find the soonest occurrence of x days without an appointment scheduled (`pendingStartDate`). Trying to use moment but I am nit sure if it is the right (or most elegant) route. NOTE: I am NOT just solving to get the first open day after ALL of the appointments, as there can be open days in between existing appointments

```js
import Moment from 'moment';
import { extendMoment } from 'moment-range';

const moment = extendMoment(Moment);

const determineStartDate = (daysNeeded, existingAppts) => {
  // this is about as far as I've gotten...
  pendingStartDate = moment();
  existingAppts.forEach((a) => {
    range = moment.range(moment(a.startDate), moment(a.endDate);
    console.log(range.contains(pendingStartDate));
  })

}

// just some dummy code to help explain
const daysNeeded = 2
const existingAppts = [
  { startDate: '2020-06-15', endDate: '2020-06-17' },
  { startDate: '2020-06-14', endDate: '2020-06-14' },
]
const pendingStartDate = determineStartDate(daysNeeded, existingAppts);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use moment for this if you dont want to.. can use javascript Date().

```
existingAppts.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aDate = new Date(a.endDate);
  var bDate = new Date(b.endDate);
  return (aDate - bDate);
});

daysNeeded = (daysNeeded > 0) ? daysNeeded - 1 : 0; 
var apptFound = false;
var apptStart;
var apptEnd;
for(var index = 0; index < (existingAppts.length - 1) && !apptFound; index++){
  apptStart = new Date(existingAppts[index].endDate);
  apptStart.setDate(apptStart.getDate() + 1);

  apptEnd = newDate();
  apptEnd.setDate(apptStart.getDate() + daysNeeded);

  var nextStart = newDate(existingAppts[index + 1].startDate);
  if(apptEnd < nextStart){
    apptFound = true;
  }
}
if(!apptFound){
  apptStart = newDate(existingAppts[existingAppts.length - 1].endDate);
  apptStart.setDate(apptStart.getDate() + 1);
  apptEnd = newDate();
  apptEnd.setDate(apptStart.getDate() + daysNeeded);
}
existingAppts.push({startDate: apptStart, endDate: apptEnd});
```

In your determineStartDate function first sort your existing appointments by endDate.  Then loop through your appointments...  potential starting date of new appointment is day after current appointment ends.  Calculate potential end date and compare to start date of next appointment in list.  If there's room then exit the loop and set the new appointment into the array.  If the loop exits with no big enough slots found, then schedule the appointment for the next day after the last appointment (or whenever as your customer would have it).

Comment: I think I may not have been clear in my question, it is possible for their to be open days in between scheduled appointments, and I am trying to solve for that

Comment: cool beans.. I did indeed misread your question... I edited my answer to reflect your need...  adapt to your specific code as needed...

Answer (score 0):

```
function determineStartDate(daysNeeded, existingAppts) { 
  // sort your existing appointments
  const sortedAppointments = existingAppts.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aDate = new Date(a.endDate);
    var bDate = new Date(b.endDate);
    return (aDate - bDate);
  });

  // potentialStartDate, start from today
  let pStartDateInUTC = Date.now()
  for (let appointment of sortedAppointments) {
    const aStartDate = new Date(appointment['startDate'])
    const aEndDate = new Date(appointment['endDate'])

    // calculate potentialEndDate
    let pEndDate = new Date(pStartDateInUTC + (daysNeeded-1) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

    // if potentialEndDate is before the startDate 
    // of the current appointment,
    // it is a valid solution
    if (pEndDate < aStartDate) {
        // match found!
        break
    }

    // else, reset potential start date to 
    // day after current appointment's end date
    pStartDateInUTC = (new Date()).setDate(aEndDate.getDate() + 1)
  }

  return new Date(pStartDateInUTC)
}
```